# What are these "hyper-distributions" called?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, density-function, dirichlet-process, measure-theory

This may be an elementary question. Say we have a univariate continuous random variable $X$ with unknown pdf $p(x)$, $ \forall x \in X$.

Presumably we can assign a second probability measure $Q(p)$ to the set of all possible realizations of the pdf $p$, define a Radon-Nikodym derivative etc.

Do these types of "hyper-distributions" have a general name? I do realize you can define distribution parameters probabilistically, I am looking for something more non-parametric.

P.S. Please let me know if my notation is incorrect!

**Edit:** There are examples of such distributions (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process), but I am looking for a more general theory.

In case it helps, below is an example:

[image: Two possible pdf]

This is a simplified discrete case. Say we have two pdf's $p_1$ and $p_2$, where each has probability 0.5 under $Q$. While you can easily marginalize out the index (i.e. the $i \in \{1, 2\}$), I am interested in the distribution of possible pdf's.

Comment: I think you are thinking of level set of probability distributions. This paper may be helpful: http://pelletierb.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Publications_files/cpp-jnps.pdf

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to a (Bayes) *prior* distribution?  Your description is not clear, because "assign a second probability measure to the set of all possible values of the pdf $p$" could be interpreted liberally, in the sense of a probability distribution over the set of all univariate distribution functions, or literally, in the sense that identifies "all possible values" with $\mathbb R$. Which is it?

Comment: @whuber Apologies about the description, I have added some more detail. I am interested in the former of the two options you describe ("probability distribution over the set of all univariate distribution functions"). They are indeed some kind of Bayesian prior distribution, but I am looking for a more specific term I can search for :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies, but it sounds a lot like what goes on in a Bayesian hierarchical model where we have some data distributed as some distribution, but at least some of those parameters are unknown, so we place a prior over the parameters themselves and the model has several layers.

Comment: @user777 Thanks, yes I think you on the right track - in fact what I am thinking of could be described as a "nonparametric hyperprior".

Comment: I've seen similar notation used in this arxiv paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6306 where they refer to it as a "prior" distribution. I'm not a fan of the name however

Comment: @GuillaumeDehaene Thanks! I will read. Any ideas for a better name?

Comment: I'd rather avoid that notation completely and use "parameter" random variables conditional on which x has a specific distribution. So in your example, I would say there is a random variable $\alpha$ such that $p(x|\alpha=1)=p_1(x)$ and $p(x|\alpha=2)=p_2(x)$ (and then specify an ordinary probability distribution on $\alpha$)